# How to migrate a Windows 10 installation of PostgreSQL 9.5.7 to a larger disk

Tags: windows, postgresql, data-migration

I installed a PostgreSQL database for the first time a few months ago, I accepted all the installation defaults and now I have a C: drive bursting at the limits. I’d like to migrate the database (i.e. the datafiles) to my D: drive where I have plenty of space.

I’ve found a couple of threads on the subject, but the information in them no longer seems to be relevant to the current version (they suggest that the datafile is passed using the `-D` parameter when the PostgreSQL database is started, this no longer seems to be the case)

This are the steps I’ve followed so far

- Checked the task manager for the PostgreSQL processes (several instances of “PostgreSQL server”)
- Shut down Postgres (start menu, PostgreSQL, Stop PostgreSQL 9.5)
- Checked the task manager for the Postgres processes (all instances of “PostgreSQL server” have stopped)
- Copied the directory that seems to contain all the datafiles to my D: drive (i.e. copied c:\PostgresSQL\data\pg95 to d:\PostgresSQL\data\pg95)
- Gave full access to the new directory to ‘NETWORK SERVICES’
- Edited c:\PostgreSQL\data\pg95\postgresql.conf to include the following new lines in the ‘FILE LOCATIONS’ section

  ```
  data_directory = 'D:\PostgreSQL\data\pg95'

  hba_file = 'C:\PostgreSQL\data\pg95\pg_hba.conf'

  ident_file = ‘C:\PostgreSQL\data\pg95\pg_ident.conf'
  ```
- Restarted Postgres (start menu, PostgreSQL, Start PostgreSQL 9.5)

The result of all this is that after checking task manager there is no sign of any Postgres processes. There are no sign of any errors when I attempt to start the process.

What’s the correct procedure to migrate PostgreSQL to a larger disk?

Comment: Did you re-create the Windows service? The location of the data directory (`-D` option) is passed to the service as a parameter, and you need to change that.

Comment: The 'path to executable' for my service is C:\PostgreSQL\pg95\pgservice.exe "//RS//PostgreSQL 9.5 Server" The threads I've encountered that mention the data directory (the '-D' option) suggest the service should be started with the following command... "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -N "postgresql-x64-9.5" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data" since these are so different to my service I assume it no longer applies?

Comment: well `-D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data"` should be `-D 'D:\PostgresSQL\data\pg95'`

Comment: The -D option seems to have no effect if the service is started with C:\PostgreSQL\pg95\pgservice.exe "//RS//PostgreSQL 9.5 Server" - sorry should have been clearer with my previous response

Comment: I have no idea what that `pgservice.exe` is - it is not part of the default Windows distribution provided by EntepriseDB

Comment: As far as I can tell I have a perfectly standard installation of PostgreSQL, I downloaded and installed it from https://www.postgresql.org/ and accepted all the default options. If I look at the windows 10 service, right click and select 'properties' it says my 'Path to executable' is C:\PostgreSQL\pg95\pgservice.exe "//RS//PostgreSQL 9.5 Server". Is there somewhere else I should be looking to see how the windows service is defined? thanks

Comment: The Windows service definition typically looks like this: `"c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -N "postgresql-9.5" -D "c:\....."`

Comment: Yes - I found that service definition in several other threads, however it doesn't seem what's used for version 9.5.7

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've managed to answer my own question.

Firstly, my 'data directory' is not

```
D:\PostgreSQL\data
```

it's

```
D:\PostgreSQL\data\pg95.
```

Secondly, despite being a windows installation, it seems PostgreSQL expects to see forward slashes in paths, so the entries in postgresql.conf need to have forward slashes, not back slashes

The PostgreSQL service is started (default settings) with the following command (start menu->PostgreSQL->Start PostgreSQL 9.5)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\sc.exe start "PostgreSQL 9.5 Server"
```

So to work with a different data file location I changed it to...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\sc.exe start "PostgreSQL 9.5 Server" -D "D:/PostgreSQL/data/pg95"
```

I was then able to restart the postgreSQL and access the database.

To prove to myself that I really was accessing the new copy (D: drive) of the datafiles and not the original (C: drive) version I renamed

```
c:\PostgresSQL\data\pg95\base to c:\PostgresSQL\data\pg95\baseXXX
```

seems to work so far!

Comment: yoju don't need to specify the data directory in `postgresql.conf` if that file is located _in_ the data directory. Passing the location when starting Postgres is enough in that case