# How to migrate a PostgreSQL 10 database from Windows C drive to another drive

Tags: windows, postgresql, data-migration, postgresql-10

I have almost an identical problem as this post:

[How to migrate a Windows 10 installation of PostgreSQL 9.5.7 to a larger disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406216/how-to-migrate-a-windows-10-installation-of-postgresql-9-5-7-to-a-larger-disk)

I have a PostgreSQL database on my C drive which is running out of space. I want to move my database to my larger F drive. I'm running into the same issue as the user in the post I mentioned:

The path to executable under the service to start my server is

`C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\pgservice.exe "//RS//PostgreSQL 10 Server"`

There's no specific path to the data directory explicitly written. I'm not sure how to change where PostgreSQL looks to store data since there's not a `-D` variable defined there.

I think if I just copy my data over to the larger drive and pass the new data directory as a parameter argument on startup, my issue would be solved. Any ideas on how to do this given my current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I won’t call it migration rather just transferring files from one location to another.

It can be done by:

- Stopping database server
- Cut/paste data to your new drive location
- reconfigure database server to use new location
- Start server again or restart system if needed

Comment: I'm having trouble with the third bullet point - how do I reconfigure the server to use the new location? As I described most examples have a ```-D``` defined in their executable whereas I do not.

Comment: @JakeLyle: see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51552216)